# Помогите разобраться с написание плагина

Tags: jquery

пишу плагин на jQuery, мне нужно передавать значение `input type="range"` в динамически созданный `span`.
Проблема в следующем, значение передаётся ко всем созданным спанам, как передавать значение спану только вызываемого экземпляра?
https://codepen.io/Jeqyrau/pen/vYBraLz

```js
;(function ($) {

    let defaults = {
        min: "0",
        max: "100",
        width: "200",
        orient: "slider-horizontal",
        orientIE: "",
        text: "value",
        colorText: "red"
    };


    $.fn.rangeSlider = function (options) {
        let config = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $('<input>', {
                type: "range",
                class: "range",
                min: config.min,
                max: config.max
            }).appendTo(this)
                .css("width", config.width)
                .css("-webkit-appearance", config.orient)
                .css("writing-mode", config.orientIE);

            (function () {
               // console.log(this)
            })();



            $('<p />', {
                text: config.text
            }).appendTo(this)
                .css("color", config.colorText)
                .append($('<span />', {
                    class: 'value'
                }));


            $('.range').on('mousemove change', function () {
                $('.value').html($(this).val())
            });


        });
    };
})(jQuery);


    
    

$('.rangeSlider').rangeSlider({
    classSpan: 'valueOne',
    width: "500",
    min: "50",
    max: "60",
    text: "another texthdhf"
});

$('.rangeSliderTwo').rangeSlider({
    classSpan: "valueTwo",
    min: "15",
    max: "75",
    colorText: "blue",
    orient: "slider-vertical",
    orientIE: "bt-lr"
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rangeSlider"></div>
<div class="rangeSliderTwo"></div>
```

Comment: пихаете рядом `p > span` дак и возьмите тогда селектор `parent -> .value`, а не просто `.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант, по сути, не один.. Нужно просто ближайший эл-т выбывать чтоб ему и писалось значение

```js
; (function ($) {

    let defaults = {
        min: "0",
        max: "100",
        width: "200",
        orient: "slider-horizontal",
        orientIE: "",
        text: "value",
        colorText: "red"
    };


    $.fn.rangeSlider = function (options) {
        let config = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
          let range = "range"+Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
            $('<input>', {
                type: "range",
                class: range,
                min: config.min,
                max: config.max
            }).appendTo(this)
                .css("width", config.width)
                .css("-webkit-appearance", config.orient)
                .css("writing-mode", config.orientIE);

            //(function () {
            //    console.log(this)
            //})();



            $('<p />', {
                text: config.text
            }).appendTo(this)
                .css("color", config.colorText)
                .append($('<span />', {
                    class: 'value'
                }));


            $("."+range).on('mousemove change', function () {
                $(this).next('p').find('.value').html($(this).val())
            });


        });
    };
})(jQuery);

//вызов плагина
$('.rangeSlider').rangeSlider({
    classSpan: 'valueOne',
    width: "500",
    min: "50",
    max: "60",
    text: "another texthdhf"
});

$('.rangeSliderTwo').rangeSlider({
    classSpan: "valueTwo",
    min: "15",
    max: "75",
    colorText: "blue",
    orient: "slider-vertical",
    orientIE: "bt-lr"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.rangeSlider.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="rangeSlider"></div>
    <div class="rangeSliderTwo"></div>

</body>

</html>
```